# Can I mount a backup generator 30A NEMA L14-30P inlet plug directly on my outdoor meter main panel?

Tags: generator

I have an outdoor meter main panel (Eaton MBE2040B200BTS) with the following circuits: 15A and 20A septic, a 30A 120v RV hookup, a 20A outdoor utility outlet, and an Eaton BRS225 Main Lug Kit that feeds my 200A indoor manufactured home panel. I want to put a generator hookup outside for backup power to keep emergency loads like the septic and refrigerator on. I understand the generator won't handle my HVAC, Water Heater, Dryer, or Range so those breakers will be turned off in the house before starting the generator. I plan to use a double pole 30A breaker and [this interlock kit](https://www.geninterlock.com/product/generator-interlock-kit-cutler-hammer-eaton-meter-main-br-panel-single-row/). Can I mount an inlet [like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/AC-WORKS-30-Amp-Locking-4-Prong-125-250-Volt-NEMA-L14-30P-Flanged-Power-Input-Inlet-With-Weather-Cover-ASINL1430P-FC/305436659) directly into the bottom or the side of the meter main panel and skip the additional inlet box and conduit? I have a hydraulic knockout kit with a 2.36" die to make a clean hole.

[image: plug]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not if it's outdoors

And the electric meter is on it, so I presume it's outdoors.

The reason is NEC requires a weatherproof cover. The same company makes those for $40 more... and you can connect them to the panel with a $3 offset nipple (which gives you 1 axis of freedom of movement to match it to surfaces).

You also have NEC 110.3(B) to contend with: "Use equipment according to labeling and instructions". That is notably applicable to your NEMA 3 rated enclosure, vis-a-vis where on the enclosure a knockout may be located.  It also applies to the inlet.  "use according to" means all uses are forbidden except the permitted ones.

Comment: Yes it's outside.  Your answer makes sense. I wasn't aware of the existence of offset nipples. Thanks.

Comment: Is the in-use cover required on inlets? The Reliance inlet boxes don't have one, for one...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can't find any support for that, removed. But it definitely needs to be weatherproof.